# Cannot sync email with Office365 when connected to home Wifi

Tags: email

My phone (a Samsung Ativ-S) is configured with an Office 365 email account for work, but this doesn't connect when I'm at home.

To be clear:

- When I connect via cellular data, email sync works fine.
- When I connect via wireless at work, it also works fine.
- When I connect via wireless at home, it **fails** with error code 80072EFD.

Suggestions I found after many hours using Google and Bing and tried in order to isolate the problem:

- Restart the phone: no change, still fails.
- Toggle Airplane mode: still fails.
- Wifi at a friends house: works fine.
- Use Fiddler on my laptop as a proxy on my home Wifi: works fine.
- Reconfigure my wireless router to use Google DNS: no change, still fails.
- Reconfigure router to use OpenDNS: no change, still fails.
- Disable IP6 on the router: no change, still fails.

I don't have mobile coverage at home, so I can't just disconnect from the Wifi, I need it to work.

It seems pretty clear that the phone itself is correctly configured (because it works on cellular and on *other* Wifi networks), so I'm sure the problem must be with my home Wifi network.

**What causes this error and how do I get email Sync to work at home?**

Comment: That error code normally indicates that it is unable to make a connection to the Internet. Are other applications able to see the Internet via WiFi on your home network (for instance, Internet Explorer)?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Most other applications on the phone work just fine - Internet Explorer, NextGen Reader, my personal email, etc. The exception is the Azure Authenticator app - it too fails on my WiFi but works elsewhere. It's error is about as helpful - "NotFound".

Comment: Are you able to connect to these servers from other devices on the same WiFi network?

Comment: @RowlandShaw A provisional yes - I can use my laptop as an HTTP proxy (using Fiddler) and everything works as it should.

Comment: I've tried both my laptop (Mail app on Windows 10) and tablet (Mail app on Windows RT) to connect and both work fine on my home WiFi.